# Principal square root of quadratic residue mod $n$, where $n$ is a Blum integer

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $n = pq$ be a Blum integer, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, and $y$ belongs to the Quadratic Residues modulo $n$ ($y \in QR(n)$).

How could I prove that the primitive square root $x$ of $y$ is given by the following formula?
$$ x = y^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)+4}{8}} mod(n)$$

This question is based on the inverse function of page 31 of [this](https://www.fi.muni.cz/usr/gruska/crypto19/appendix.pdf)
set of notes.